How to setup the C# solution such as internal and NuGet dependencies be resolved on any PC without additional PC-dependent manual settings?
When I have checked out my solution (main language is C#) on another PC, I got many errors:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  NU1102  Unable to find package Newtonsoft.Json with version (>= 13.0.3)
  - Found 1 version(s) in Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages [ Nearest version: 13.0.1 ]
  - Found 0 version(s) in C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs Utils   D:\Documents\NativeDevelopment\ExperimentalCSharpApplication1\Incubators\Utils\Utils.csproj 1   
Error (active)  NU1101  Unable to find package RandomDataGenerator.Net. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages    Utils   D:\Documents\NativeDevelopment\ExperimentalCSharpApplication1\Incubators\Utils\Utils.csproj 1   
Error (active)  NU1101  Unable to find package YamatoDaiwaCS_Extensions. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages   Utils   D:\Documents\NativeDevelopment\ExperimentalCSharpApplication1\Incubators\Utils\Utils.csproj 1   
Error (active)  NU1101  Unable to find package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages  EntityFramework D:\Documents\NativeDevelopment\ExperimentalCSharpApplication1\Implementation\Reusables\EntityFramework\EntityFramework.csproj   1   
Error (active)  NU1101  Unable to find package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages   EntityFramework D:\Documents\NativeDevelopment\ExperimentalCSharpApplication1\Implementation\Reusables\EntityFramework\EntityFramework.csproj   1   
Error (active)  NU1101  Unable to find package YamatoDaiwaCS_Extensions.Localizations.Japanese. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages    FrontEndFramework   D:\Documents\NativeDevelopment\ExperimentalCSharpApplication1\Incubators\FrontEndFramework\FrontEndFramework.csproj 1   
Error (active)  NU1101  Unable to find package YamatoDaiwaCS_Extensions. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages   FrontEndFramework   D:\Documents\NativeDevelopment\ExperimentalCSharpApplication1\Incubators\FrontEndFramework\FrontEndFramework.csproj 1   
Error (active)  NU1101  Unable to find package YamatoDaiwaFrontend. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages    FrontEndFramework   D:\Documents\NativeDevelopment\ExperimentalCSharpApplication1\Incubators\FrontEndFramework\FrontEndFramework.csproj 1   
Error (active)  NU1101  Unable to find package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages    FrontEndFramework   D:\Documents\NativeDevelopment\ExperimentalCSharpApplication1\Incubators\FrontEndFramework\FrontEndFramework.csproj 1   
...

Well, currently I don't understand how linking between projects works and also how NuGet installs the dependencies. Before use the C#, I was knew well only the npm. It's pretty portable: once checkout the project on another PC, all that required is run npm install and everything will be installed. For the monorepositories with multiple projects (similar to solutions with multiple projects), besides the npm workspaces, the resolution by relative paths is also available.
Before start the deep analysis of the errors, I can assume that the NuGet is not such portable as npm. I know that the NuGet is another tool, but I have expected from the NuGet and C# solutions at whole the correct resolution of dependencies on any PC. De facto, the development from the multiple PCs is the basic requirement for the third decade of 21the century.
Own Efforts: Errors Analyzing

Error (active)  NU1102  Unable to find package Newtonsoft.Json with version (>= 13.0.3)

The 13.0.3 is the newest version of Newtonsoft.Json for 6th June of 2024.
It have been mentioned in 2 projects of my solution like:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="RandomDataGenerator.Net" Version="1.0.17" />
    <PackageReference Include="YamatoDaiwaCS_Extensions" Version="0.0.9" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>

Why NuGet has not automatically installed it after the solution has been checked out?

Error (active)  NU1101  Unable to find package RandomDataGenerator.Net.
No packages exist with this id in source(s):
C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages    Utils   D:\Documents\NativeDevelopment\ExperimentalCSharpApplication1\Incubators\Utils\Utils.csproj 1

I don't know why the NuGet does not install the library below the solution directory.
In other project the another version of same dependency could required, could not it?
Well, if "No packages exist", why not automatically install them?
The following errors are similar.
Appendix
Full listing of errors
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  NU1102  Unable to find package Newtonsoft.Json with version (>= 13.0.3)
  - Found 1 version(s) in Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages [ Nearest version: 13.0.1 ]
  - Found 0 version(s) in C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs Utils   D:\Documents\NativeDevelopment\ExperimentalCSharpApplication1\Incubators\Utils\Utils.csproj 1   
Error (active)  NU1101  Unable to find package RandomDataGenerator.Net. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages    Utils   D:\Documents\NativeDevelopment\ExperimentalCSharpApplication1\Incubators\Utils\Utils.csproj 1   
Error (active)  NU1101  Unable to find package YamatoDaiwaCS_Extensions. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages   Utils   D:\Documents\NativeDevelopment\ExperimentalCSharpApplication1\Incubators\Utils\Utils.csproj 1   
Error (active)  NU1101  Unable to find package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages  EntityFramework D:\Documents\NativeDevelopment\ExperimentalCSharpApplication1\Implementation\Reusables\EntityFramework\EntityFramework.csproj   1   
Error (active)  NU1101  Unable to find package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages   EntityFramework D:\Documents\NativeDevelopment\ExperimentalCSharpApplication1\Implementation\Reusables\EntityFramework\EntityFramework.csproj   1   
Error (active)  NU1101  Unable to find package YamatoDaiwaCS_Extensions.Localizations.Japanese. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages    FrontEndFramework   D:\Documents\NativeDevelopment\ExperimentalCSharpApplication1\Incubators\FrontEndFramework\FrontEndFramework.csproj 1   
Error (active)  NU1101  Unable to find package YamatoDaiwaCS_Extensions. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages   FrontEndFramework   D:\Documents\NativeDevelopment\ExperimentalCSharpApplication1\Incubators\FrontEndFramework\FrontEndFramework.csproj 1   
Error (active)  NU1101  Unable to find package YamatoDaiwaFrontend. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages    FrontEndFramework   D:\Documents\NativeDevelopment\ExperimentalCSharpApplication1\Incubators\FrontEndFramework\FrontEndFramework.csproj 1   
Error (active)  NU1101  Unable to find package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages    FrontEndFramework   D:\Documents\NativeDevelopment\ExperimentalCSharpApplication1\Incubators\FrontEndFramework\FrontEndFramework.csproj 1   
Error (active)  NU1101  Unable to find package RandomDataGenerator.Net. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages    FrontEndFramework   D:\Documents\NativeDevelopment\ExperimentalCSharpApplication1\Incubators\FrontEndFramework\FrontEndFramework.csproj 1   
Error (active)  NU1102  Unable to find package Newtonsoft.Json with version (>= 13.0.3)
  - Found 1 version(s) in Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages [ Nearest version: 13.0.1 ]
  - Found 0 version(s) in C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs FrontEndFramework   D:\Documents\NativeDevelopment\ExperimentalCSharpApplication1\Incubators\FrontEndFramework\FrontEndFramework.csproj 1   
Error (active)  NU1101  Unable to find package RandomDataGenerator.Net. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages    MockDataSource  D:\Documents\NativeDevelopment\ExperimentalCSharpApplication1\Implementation\Elements\MockDataSource\MockDataSource.csproj  1   
Error (active)  NU1101  Unable to find package YamatoDaiwaCS_Extensions. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages   MockDataSource  D:\Documents\NativeDevelopment\ExperimentalCSharpApplication1\Implementation\Elements\MockDataSource\MockDataSource.csproj  1   
Error (active)  NU1102  Unable to find package Newtonsoft.Json with version (>= 13.0.3)
  - Found 1 version(s) in Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages [ Nearest version: 13.0.1 ]
  - Found 0 version(s) in C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs MockDataSource  D:\Documents\NativeDevelopment\ExperimentalCSharpApplication1\Implementation\Elements\MockDataSource\MockDataSource.csproj  1   
Error (active)  NU1101  Unable to find package YamatoDaiwaCS_Extensions. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages   Client (net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0) D:\Documents\NativeDevelopment\ExperimentalCSharpApplication1\Implementation\Elements\Client\Client.csproj  1   
Error (active)  NU1101  Unable to find package YamatoDaiwaFrontend. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages    Client (net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0) D:\Documents\NativeDevelopment\ExperimentalCSharpApplication1\Implementation\Elements\Client\Client.csproj  1   
Error (active)  NU1101  Unable to find package Microsoft.Data.Sqlite. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages  Client (net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0) D:\Documents\NativeDevelopment\ExperimentalCSharpApplication1\Implementation\Elements\Client\Client.csproj  1   
Error (active)  NU1101  Unable to find package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages  Client (net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0) D:\Documents\NativeDevelopment\ExperimentalCSharpApplication1\Implementation\Elements\Client\Client.csproj  1   
Error (active)  NU1101  Unable to find package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages   Client (net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0) D:\Documents\NativeDevelopment\ExperimentalCSharpApplication1\Implementation\Elements\Client\Client.csproj  1   
Error (active)  NU1101  Unable to find package Microsoft.NET.ILLink.Tasks. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages Client (net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0) D:\Documents\NativeDevelopment\ExperimentalCSharpApplication1\Implementation\Elements\Client\Client.csproj  1   
Error (active)  NU1101  Unable to find package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages Client (net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0) D:\Documents\NativeDevelopment\ExperimentalCSharpApplication1\Implementation\Elements\Client\Client.csproj  1   
Error (active)  NU1101  Unable to find package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebView. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages    Client (net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0) D:\Documents\NativeDevelopment\ExperimentalCSharpApplication1\Implementation\Elements\Client\Client.csproj  1   
Error (active)  NU1101  Unable to find package Microsoft.JSInterop. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages    Client (net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0) D:\Documents\NativeDevelopment\ExperimentalCSharpApplication1\Implementation\Elements\Client\Client.csproj  1   
Error (active)  NU1101  Unable to find package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages Client (net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0) D:\Documents\NativeDevelopment\ExperimentalCSharpApplication1\Implementation\Elements\Client\Client.csproj  1   
Error (active)  NU1101  Unable to find package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages  Client (net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0) D:\Documents\NativeDevelopment\ExperimentalCSharpApplication1\Implementation\Elements\Client\Client.csproj  1   
Error (active)  NU1101  Unable to find package RandomDataGenerator.Net. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages    Client (net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0) D:\Documents\NativeDevelopment\ExperimentalCSharpApplication1\Implementation\Elements\Client\Client.csproj  1   
Error (active)  NU1101  Unable to find package YamatoDaiwaCS_Extensions.Localizations.Japanese. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages    Client (net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0) D:\Documents\NativeDevelopment\ExperimentalCSharpApplication1\Implementation\Elements\Client\Client.csproj  1   
Error (active)  NU1101  Unable to find package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages    Client (net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0) D:\Documents\NativeDevelopment\ExperimentalCSharpApplication1\Implementation\Elements\Client\Client.csproj  1   
Error (active)  NU1101  Unable to find package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages   Client (net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0) D:\Documents\NativeDevelopment\ExperimentalCSharpApplication1\Implementation\Elements\Client\Client.csproj  1   
Error (active)  NU1101  Unable to find package Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages   Client (net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0) D:\Documents\NativeDevelopment\ExperimentalCSharpApplication1\Implementation\Elements\Client\Client.csproj  1   
Error (active)  NU1101  Unable to find package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages   Client (net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0) D:\Documents\NativeDevelopment\ExperimentalCSharpApplication1\Implementation\Elements\Client\Client.csproj  1   
Error (active)  NU1101  Unable to find package Xamarin.Android.Glide. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages  Client (net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0) D:\Documents\NativeDevelopment\ExperimentalCSharpApplication1\Implementation\Elements\Client\Client.csproj  1   
Error (active)  NU1101  Unable to find package Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.LiveData. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages    Client (net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0) D:\Documents\NativeDevelopment\ExperimentalCSharpApplication1\Implementation\Elements\Client\Client.csproj  1   
Error (active)  NU1101  Unable to find package Xamarin.AndroidX.Navigation.Common. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages Client (net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0) D:\Documents\NativeDevelopment\ExperimentalCSharpApplication1\Implementation\Elements\Client\Client.csproj  1   
Error (active)  NU1101  Unable to find package Xamarin.AndroidX.Navigation.Fragment. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages   Client (net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0) D:\Documents\NativeDevelopment\ExperimentalCSharpApplication1\Implementation\Elements\Client\Client.csproj  1   
Error (active)  NU1101  Unable to find package Xamarin.AndroidX.Navigation.Runtime. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages    Client (net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0) D:\Documents\NativeDevelopment\ExperimentalCSharpApplication1\Implementation\Elements\Client\Client.csproj  1   
Error (active)  NU1101  Unable to find package Xamarin.AndroidX.Navigation.UI. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages Client (net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0) D:\Documents\NativeDevelopment\ExperimentalCSharpApplication1\Implementation\Elements\Client\Client.csproj  1   
Error (active)  NU1101  Unable to find package Xamarin.AndroidX.SwipeRefreshLayout. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages    Client (net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0) D:\Documents\NativeDevelopment\ExperimentalCSharpApplication1\Implementation\Elements\Client\Client.csproj  1   
Error (active)  NU1101  Unable to find package Xamarin.Google.Android.Material. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages    Client (net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0) D:\Documents\NativeDevelopment\ExperimentalCSharpApplication1\Implementation\Elements\Client\Client.csproj  1   
Error (active)  NU1101  Unable to find package Xamarin.AndroidX.Browser. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages   Client (net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0) D:\Documents\NativeDevelopment\ExperimentalCSharpApplication1\Implementation\Elements\Client\Client.csproj  1   
Error (active)  NU1101  Unable to find package Xamarin.AndroidX.Security.SecurityCrypto. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages   Client (net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0) D:\Documents\NativeDevelopment\ExperimentalCSharpApplication1\Implementation\Elements\Client\Client.csproj  1   
Error (active)  NU1101  Unable to find package Xamarin.Google.Crypto.Tink.Android. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages Client (net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0) D:\Documents\NativeDevelopment\ExperimentalCSharpApplication1\Implementation\Elements\Client\Client.csproj  1   
Error (active)  NU1102  Unable to find package Newtonsoft.Json with version (>= 13.0.3)
  - Found 1 version(s) in Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages [ Nearest version: 13.0.1 ]
  - Found 0 version(s) in C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs Client (net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0) D:\Documents\NativeDevelopment\ExperimentalCSharpApplication1\Implementation\Elements\Client\Client.csproj  1   
Error (active)  NU1101  Unable to find package Microsoft.Graphics.Win2D. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages   Client (net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0) D:\Documents\NativeDevelopment\ExperimentalCSharpApplication1\Implementation\Elements\Client\Client.csproj  1   
Error (active)  NU1101  Unable to find package Microsoft.WindowsAppSDK. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages    Client (net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0) D:\Documents\NativeDevelopment\ExperimentalCSharpApplication1\Implementation\Elements\Client\Client.csproj  1   
Error (active)  NU1101  Unable to find package Microsoft.Windows.SDK.NET.Ref. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages  Client (net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0) D:\Documents\NativeDevelopment\ExperimentalCSharpApplication1\Implementation\Elements\Client\Client.csproj  1   
Error (active)  NU1101  Unable to find package RandomDataGenerator.Net. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages    DummyDataForStaticPreviewPreparator D:\Documents\NativeDevelopment\ExperimentalCSharpApplication1\Automation\DummyDataForStaticPreviewPreparator\DummyDataForStaticPreviewPreparator.csproj 1   
Error (active)  NU1101  Unable to find package YamatoDaiwaCS_Extensions. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages   DummyDataForStaticPreviewPreparator D:\Documents\NativeDevelopment\ExperimentalCSharpApplication1\Automation\DummyDataForStaticPreviewPreparator\DummyDataForStaticPreviewPreparator.csproj 1   
Error (active)  NU1102  Unable to find package Newtonsoft.Json with version (>= 13.0.3)
  - Found 1 version(s) in Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages [ Nearest version: 13.0.1 ]
  - Found 0 version(s) in C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs DummyDataForStaticPreviewPreparator D:\Documents\NativeDevelopment\ExperimentalCSharpApplication1\Automation\DummyDataForStaticPreviewPreparator\DummyDataForStaticPreviewPreparator.csproj 1   
Error (active)  NU1101  Unable to find package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages  FrontServer D:\Documents\NativeDevelopment\ExperimentalCSharpApplication1\Implementation\Elements\FrontServer\FrontServer.csproj    1   
Error (active)  NU1101  Unable to find package Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages  FrontServer D:\Documents\NativeDevelopment\ExperimentalCSharpApplication1\Implementation\Elements\FrontServer\FrontServer.csproj    1   
Error (active)  NU1101  Unable to find package RandomDataGenerator.Net. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages    FrontServer D:\Documents\NativeDevelopment\ExperimentalCSharpApplication1\Implementation\Elements\FrontServer\FrontServer.csproj    1   
Error (active)  NU1101  Unable to find package YamatoDaiwaCS_Extensions. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages   FrontServer D:\Documents\NativeDevelopment\ExperimentalCSharpApplication1\Implementation\Elements\FrontServer\FrontServer.csproj    1   
Error (active)  NU1101  Unable to find package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages  FrontServer D:\Documents\NativeDevelopment\ExperimentalCSharpApplication1\Implementation\Elements\FrontServer\FrontServer.csproj    1   
Error (active)  NU1101  Unable to find package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages   FrontServer D:\Documents\NativeDevelopment\ExperimentalCSharpApplication1\Implementation\Elements\FrontServer\FrontServer.csproj    1   
Error (active)  NU1102  Unable to find package Newtonsoft.Json with version (>= 13.0.3)
  - Found 1 version(s) in Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages [ Nearest version: 13.0.1 ]
  - Found 0 version(s) in C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs FrontServer D:\Documents\NativeDevelopment\ExperimentalCSharpApplication1\Implementation\Elements\FrontServer\FrontServer.csproj    1   
Warning (active)    NU1603  Client depends on Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebView.Maui (>= 8.0.7) but Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebView.Maui 8.0.7 was not found. An approximate best match of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebView.Maui 8.0.21 was resolved.  Client (net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0) D:\Documents\NativeDevelopment\ExperimentalCSharpApplication1\Implementation\Elements\Client\Client.csproj  1   
Warning (active)    NU1603  Client depends on Microsoft.Maui.Controls (>= 8.0.7) but Microsoft.Maui.Controls 8.0.7 was not found. An approximate best match of Microsoft.Maui.Controls 8.0.21 was resolved. Client (net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0) D:\Documents\NativeDevelopment\ExperimentalCSharpApplication1\Implementation\Elements\Client\Client.csproj  1   
Warning (active)    NU1603  Microsoft.Maui.Core 8.0.21 depends on Microsoft.Windows.SDK.BuildTools (>= 10.0.22621.756) but Microsoft.Windows.SDK.BuildTools 10.0.22621.756 was not found. An approximate best match of Microsoft.Windows.SDK.BuildTools 10.0.22621.3233 was resolved.   Client (net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0) D:\Documents\NativeDevelopment\ExperimentalCSharpApplication1\Implementation\Elements\Client\Client.csproj  1

Repository
Currently my project has no sensitive code/data so I can share it.
 GitHub repository
If you will clone this repo, please make sure that you have checked out the @issue/unknown_stop_of_debugger branch.
Checking of "Tools => Options => NuGet Package Manager => Package sources"
The path is:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\



It seems the (default) online source for NuGet packages is missing. It's only looking at local folders. Can you check if https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json exists under Tools => Options => NuGet Package Manager => Package sources?

Do you have a file called Nuget.Config anywhere in your project? That one controls the available Nuget sources. There's also a global file of that name in %appdata%\nuget.

And yes, if the source of those packages is registered on the other PC, then a Build in Visual Studio will get those packages. In fact the error says so: it tries to download them, but cannot find them in the configured sources

@Lennart Thank you for the comment. I have checked the with setting you have mentioned. The path is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages".
I also have added the screenshot to the end of question field.

@PMF Thank you for the comment. Looks like there is no " Nuget.Config" in my project.
Should I add it to each project of my solution?

@HansKeﬆing Thank you for the comment.
Why NuGet does not store the dependencies inside the solution like npm does? The binding of the paths to local marching is the big problem for the team development, is not it?

For the real reason why name/version is stored instead of the actual URL, you will have to ask the developers. But this allows you to store a local copy, or test a new version of your own package before posting to NuGet

@TakeshiTokugawaYD You don't need to add it to each project. You can add just one file at the root of your solution. Nuget searches the project directory and all its parent folders for this file, additionally to the global one in %appdata%\nuget.

It seems the default package source is missing on that computer. It should look like this:

Name: nuget.org
Source: https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
You can add a new entry via the "+" on the top right of the dialog.
If you want to make sure the source is checked into the repository, you can add a nuget.config file in the same directory as your .sln. The contents would look like this:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>


Thank you for the answer! If I have understood you correctly, the action you have described will change the configuration only for current PC, but it will be nothing to commit. So, if the other team member will checkout the repository, he will deal with same issue. Is there the way to configure resolving of NuGet packages once?

@TakeshiTokugawaYD Normally this entry should exist by default, I don't know why it's missing on that particular computer. Additionally, you can add a nuget.config file to your repository that contains the same information and is checked into source control. I amended my answer.
